# not able to import csv file from an html page to google sheets

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am creating a drop down functionality to import a csv file to google sheets using apps script but it shows the error : cannot read properties of undefined (on console.logging it seems the formData being sent is empty)

here is my javascript code:

```
var dropArea = document.getElementById('drop-area');
var columnsInput = document.getElementById('columns');
var filterColumnInput = document.getElementById('filterColumn');
var filterValueInput = document.getElementById('filterValue');
var sheetNameInput = document.getElementById('sheetName');

dropArea.addEventListener('dragover', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  dropArea.style.backgroundColor = '#f7f7f7';
});

dropArea.addEventListener('dragleave', function() {
  dropArea.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
});

dropArea.addEventListener('drop', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  dropArea.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';

  var file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
  var columns = columnsInput.value || ''; // Default to empty string if undefined
  var filterColumn = filterColumnInput.value || ''; // Default to empty string if undefined
  var filterValue = filterValueInput.value || ''; // Default to empty string if undefined
  var sheetName = sheetNameInput.value || 'DefaultSheet'; // Get the sheet name or use 'DefaultSheet' as default

  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', file,file.name);
  formData.append('columns', columns);//which column to import
  formData.append('filterColumn', filterColumn);//appending filter column
  formData.append('filterValue', filterValue);//appending filter value
  formData.append('sheetName', sheetName); // Append the sheetName parameter
  console.log(columnsInput.value);
  console.log(filterColumnInput.value);
  console.log(filterValueInput.value);

  fetch('https://script.google.com/macros/s/sample/exec', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
  })
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => {
    if (data === 'Success') {
      alert('CSV File Imported Successfully!');
    } else {
     
      alert('Error: ' + data);
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
    alert('Error: ' + error.message);
  });
});
```

and here is my apps script code

```
function doPost(e) {
  var headers = {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, x-requested-with",
    "Access-Control-Max-Age": "86400" // 24 hours
  }

  try {
     
    var fileBlob = e.parameter.file;
    var columnsToImport = e.parameter.columns.split(',');
    var filterColumn = parseInt(e.parameter.filterColumn);
    var filterValue = e.parameter.filterValue;
    var sheetName = e.parameter.sheetName;
    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(fileBlob.getBlob().getDataAsString());
    var headersRow = csvData[0];
    var columnIndex = [];

    // Find column indices for selected columns
    columnsToImport.forEach(function(column) {
      columnIndex.push(headersRow.indexOf(column));
    });

    // Filter data based on user input
    var filteredData = csvData.filter(function(row) {
      return row[filterColumn] === filterValue;
    });

    // Prepare data for import
    var importData = filteredData.map(function(row) {
      return columnIndex.map(function(index) {
        return row[index];
      });
    });

    // Import data into the active sheet (you can modify this to target a specific sheet)
    var spreadsheetId = 'sheetid';
    var sheetName = 'test sheet'; 
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName);

    // Append data to the sheet
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, importData.length, importData[0].length).setValues(importData);

    // Return success message
    return ContentService.createTextOutput('Success').setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log(error);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput('Error: ' + error.message).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPAoO.png)

I have tried to console.log everything only the form data is empty but cannot seem to figure out the error can someone help me?

Comment: I would check the `e` parameter to `doPost`.  I suspect there is no `e.parameter`.

Comment: Rewrite the [mcve] to focus on that single issue and nothing else and make it easy to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your showing script, I was worried that the file blob could not be directly sent by directly using the file object with `new FormData()` with the fetch API. In this case, how about converting the file object to the int8array? By this, I think that the data can be sent to Google Apps Script with the fetch API.

When this is reflected in your showing script, how about the following modification?

#### Javascript side:

##### From:

```
dropArea.addEventListener('drop', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  dropArea.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';

  var file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
  var columns = columnsInput.value || ''; // Default to empty string if undefined
  var filterColumn = filterColumnInput.value || ''; // Default to empty string if undefined
  var filterValue = filterValueInput.value || ''; // Default to empty string if undefined
  var sheetName = sheetNameInput.value || 'DefaultSheet'; // Get the sheet name or use 'DefaultSheet' as default

  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', file,file.name);
```

##### To:

```
dropArea.addEventListener('drop', async function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  dropArea.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';

  var file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
  var columns = columnsInput.value || ''; // Default to empty string if undefined
  var filterColumn = filterColumnInput.value || ''; // Default to empty string if undefined
  var filterValue = filterValueInput.value || ''; // Default to empty string if undefined
  var sheetName = sheetNameInput.value || 'DefaultSheet'; // Get the sheet name or use 'DefaultSheet' as default

  var fr = new FileReader();
  fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  await new Promise(resolve => {
    fr.onload = _ => resolve();
  });
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', JSON.stringify({filename: file.name, mimeType: file.type, data: [...new Int8Array(fr.result)]}));
```

#### Google Apps Script side:

##### From:

```
var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(fileBlob.getBlob().getDataAsString());
```

##### To:

```
var file = JSON.parse(e.parameter.file);
var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(Utilities.newBlob(file.data, file.mimeType, file.filename).getDataAsString());
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that your values of CSV data, `columns`, `filterColumn`, `filterValue`, `sheetName` are valid values for using your script. Please be careful about this.
- **When you modify the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the details of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".